# Data from the SQL is not loading within AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have tried to retrieve some data from the SQL but it does not work.

I have the PHP working fine.

I think the ANGULARJS Controller is having some problems.

Here are the codes:

[PHP]

```
require_once 'connect.php';
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `calendars`") or die(mysqli_error());
$data = array();

while($row = $query->fetch_array()){
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

[AngularJS Controller]

```
function CalendarCtrl($scope,$http) {

$http.get('../crud/calendars_read.php').then(function(response){
    //$scope.calendar = [];
    $scope.calendars = response.data;

});

$scope.events = [

    {title: $scope.calendars.calendar_title,
    start: new Date(2017, 8, 2)},
// This Part does not work.

    {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
// This Part works well if there is no $scope calling as above.
];
```

I think the $scope.event is in array, and that is why $scope.calendars is not working. Can anyone please help me how to retrieve

```
$scope.calendars.calendar_title
```

from the query to the array?

Thank you in advance and have a great day!!

Answer (score 0):

http get is async, it will continue run `$scope.events` without waiting `response.data` back, so `$scope.calendars.calendar_title` is not defined yet at this timing.

Try to move `$scope.events` into `then` function.

```
$http.get('../crud/calendars_read.php').then(function(response){
    //$scope.calendar = [];
    $scope.calendars = response.data;

    $scope.events = [

        {title: $scope.calendars.calendar_title,
        start: new Date(2017, 8, 2)},

        {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, if I try your way, the whole function does not retrieve the data. Do you know why?

Comment: If I have the SQL table and column name "calendar_title", then isn't $scope.calendars.calendar_title the proper way to call out?